# How to use a specific managed object to construct a sort descriptor?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

Entity B (Book) has a one-to-many relationship with the entity D (Description). The idea is that a book has different descriptions for different languages.

I want to sort books based on their titles (D.title) for a given language (D.languageID)

If B had one-to-one relationship to D, I would do something like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"d.title" ascending:YES];
```

Of course, you may say, the model does not prevent a book from having many descriptions with the same languageID. But in this case any (e.g. the first) description would be ok for me. Or I can fetch the needed Description object before, but then how to use it in the sorting?

Is my model wrong? What's the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort via a one to many as you have already realized.  The "cleanest" way to do this would be to implement your own sort that you can perform *in memory* after the book entities have been fetched.  Once it is in memory you can sort via a convenience method instead of just data.

For example, you could have a method on your Book subclass that is called `-localTitle` which returns the appropriate title from the right description.  From there you could sort on `localTitle`.

Basically:

1. You would create a `NSFetchedResultsController` to track changes.
2. When a change is detected you re-create an array that is sorted by the `localTitle`
3. You tell your table view to reload
4. Your table view feeds off the array and NOT the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

You could do away with the `NSFetchedResultsController` but that gets a little more complicated.